# clientx property with mousedown is not giving desired coordinate?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following code, I want the mouse position within the red button, for that, I have used `clientX` property with `mousedown` event.

but `mousedown` is not giving expected result instead it is giving `clientX` property in whole parent div?

In docs, it is mentioned that `clientx` will return mouse x position in local dom content and that should be the button!

link: http://devdocs.io/dom_events/mousedown

try clicking on the right most button, I already did `console.log` the value and the result are around -600 but it should be positive and within 60 range, why is the event not getting the correct value?

code: https://jsfiddle.net/nk2059sf/

```js
var button1 = document.querySelector("#button1"),
button2 = document.querySelector("#button2"),
slider = document.querySelector(".slider"),
ae = 0,
be = 0,
sliderwidth = slider.clientWidth;
button1.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
   var e = e||window.event;
   ae = e.clientX;
   console.log(ae);
});
 button2.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
  var e = e||window.event;
 be = button2.clientWidth - e.clientX;
  console.log(be);
});
```

```css
html, body{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
   .slider{
  max-width:700px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#a0a0a0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.slider div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.button{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-radius:30px;
  background-color:red;
  z-index: 100;
}
.button:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.range{
  flex-grow:2;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
  margin: 0 -30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="button" id="button1"></div>
    <div class="range"></div>
    <div class="button" id="button2"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: clientX of the right button is coming correct with positive value. The negative value is because of your calculation (button2.clientWidth - e.clientX). It is not just clientX determine the poistion, its both x and y that determines.

Comment: `button2.clintWidth`is just width of the button2, and for button2 I want the position of the mouse from the right end, that's it. And that way it should be positive because the width of the button is 60px.